# print string to screen using polling (memory mapped I/O) in mips

Tags: memory, assembly, mips, computer-science, polling

How do i print a string to the screen using memory mapped I/O in MIPS assembly? For example, if a user inputs "A" then how do I print "you chose option 1"? I know how to do it without polling but can't seem to get started using memory mapped I/O. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not enough information. To print you don't normally need polling. For taking input, you might. Polling in general means you periodically check some condition, in this case whether a key has been pressed or not. How you do it depends on your actual hardware environment.

Comment: My code has to be assembly in MIPS and the requirements are to get user input and  print out a statement using polling method (memory mapped I/O).

Comment: http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch14s03.html

Comment: It should depend on your system (peripherals).